# Reactions of P2O5 and P4O10 with sulfuric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecules

I have  seen two reactions of $\ce{H2SO4}$, in one it reacts with $\ce{P2O5}$ and in the other $\ce{P4O10}$.

The Reactions are as follows:

$$\ce{H2SO4 + P2O5 -> SO3 + 2HPO3}$$

$$\ce{6H2SO4 + P4O10 -> 6SO3 + 4H3PO4 }$$

Since it is a dehydration reaction the oxidation states of sulphur and phosphorous would be the same in reactant and product, this is true for both the reactions.

Are the both Products correct $\ce{HPO3}$ and $\ce{H3PO4}$  correct?
If yes what I am missing?

Comment: P2O5 and P4O10 is the same thing.

Comment: I agree with Ivan Neretin. Basically, $\ce{P4O_{10}}$ is the dimeric form of  $\ce{P2O_{5}}$.

Comment: To clarify, read [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/is-the-proper-formula-for-phosphorus-oxidev-p4o10-or-p2o5).

Comment: Yes @IvanNeretin ... I agree with it but why two different products . Then may be one of them is incorrect then which one ?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I object. P4O10 is ***the only*** form of P2O5 (not counting the polymeric forms, that is). There is no monomer of which it is a dimer.

Comment: As for the reactions, both are correct.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin: Well received. I was just fugaratively speaking. See my answer for confirmation.

Comment: Note that $\ce{P4O10}$ is one of four polymorphs of phosphorus pentoxide and is meta stable, prepared by its rapid vapor condensation. The other three are polymeric. It makes an analogy to elemental phosphorus. // Therefore,not every $\ce{P2O5}$ is $\ce{P4O10}$.

Comment: @AyushShankaram A more specific question would be: "Which product formation is more preferred, H3PO4 or HPO3?". Since the anhydride(P4O10) is removing water, it will always want to form the highest hydrate possible which is H3PO4  ($\ce{P4O10 + 6 H2O → 4 H3PO4}$). HPO3 is the lowest hydrate of the anhydride and it forms when phoshoric acid loses water through heat ($\ce{H3PO4 ->[\Delta] HPO3 + H2O}$). Since the reaction doesn't involves heat, it proceeds to form H3PO4.

Comment: @Nilayghosh The question is, if water activity in anhydrous H2SO4 is high enough for forming H3PO4. It may quite well be equivalent to heating of H3PO4.

Answer (score 2):

[Phosphorus pentoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_pentoxide) is the common name of a chemical with molecular formula $\ce{P4O10}$. The common name is derived from its empirical formula, $\ce{P2O5}$. This white crystalline solid is the anhydride of phosphoric acid:

[image: Phosphorus pentoxide]

It is a potent dehydrating agent and used as a powerful desiccant (as indicated by the exothermic nature of its hydrolysis) in limited capacity:
$$\ce{P4O10 + 6H2O -> 4H3PO4} \qquad \Delta H = \pu{-177 kJ}$$

However, the desiccating power of $\ce{P4O10}$ is strong enough to convert many mineral acids to their anhydrides. For examples, $\ce{H2SO4}$ is converted to $\ce{SO3}$:
$$\ce{P4O10 + 6H2SO4 -> 6SO3 + 4H3PO4} $$

Therefore, it can be concluded that the second reaction is the correct one (although it may or may not be balanced). The first one is incorrect, solely based on the fact that $\ce{P2O5}$ does not exist.

Comment: Hm, I have never seen P4O10 during describing dyhydration reactions to produce H3PO4. Especially when dehydrating other dehydrating agens. I usually see written the product as polymetaphosphoric acid (HPO3)n